# Prove $f^{-1} : f(A) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $f^{-1} : f(A) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous

Let $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ be an injective and continuous function and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact

Since f is continuous and $A$ is compact then $f(A)$ is compact

and since $f$ is injective, $\forall y \in f(A), \exists! x \in A \ni f(x) = y$

I'm not sure if this needs a $\varepsilon$-$\delta$  proof or some other proof.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it's a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.  It suffices to show that if $B\subseteq A$ is closed, then $f(B)$ is closed.  Since $B$ is a closed subset of a compact set, it is compact.  Therefore $f(B)$ is compact and hence closed.

Comment: I know, that's why my last comment says im not sure which proof this needs to get to $f^{-1}$ being continuous

Comment: I've given you an argument show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: and preimage of a closed set under some continuous function is also a closed set. What's the importance of $f$ being injective then?

Comment: If $f$ isn't injective, $f^{-1}$ isn't a function

Comment: @user251257 oh yeah, duh.